# Disable icon 'i' in dependent picklist in detail page

Tags: custom-field, picklist, dependent-picklist, detail-page

Is it possible to disable the 'i' icon for a dependent picklist dependent values in salesforce detail page? If can't be removed, atleast if modifying the text shown on hovering the icon needs to be changed as per my requirement.

Comment: screen shot would make this question clearer